# how can i sort array which is create of a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

```
function sortpm($parameters){
if(strpos($parameters,"&")!==false){
    foreach(explode("&",$parameters) as $pmsplit){
        $key = explode("=",$pmsplit)[0];
        $value = explode("=",$pmsplit)[1];
        $fields[]=[$key=>$value];
    }
   $parameters = ksort($fields);
}else{
        $parameters = $parameters;
}
print_r($parameters);
}
```

when i get sortpm("z=4&a=2");
array are not sorted by keys

i want this output: Array ( [a] => 2[z] => 4 )

Comment: What's the actual output ? I get `1` when I run your function with the provided input. Also, you should probably use [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ksort` will sort the `$fields` array and will return a boolean. You would want something like this:

```
$parameters = $fields;
ksort($parameters);
```

There are also some unnecessary things happening here. I would rewrite your code like this:

```
function sortpm($parameters){
    // Make sure to set a default value to your variables
    $fields = [];
    // No need for the if case - explode will always return an array
    foreach(explode("&",$parameters) as $pmsplit){
        // Instead of exploding twice - explode once, but set a limit
        $exploded = explode("=", $pmsplit, 2);
        // If there is no second parameter, fill in a null value
        $fields[$exploded[0]]= isset($exploded[1]) ? $exploded[1] : null;
    }
   ksort($fields);
   print_r($fields);
}
```

Alternatively you could use parse_str as [AymDev pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68678038/how-can-i-sort-array-which-is-create-of-a-loop/68678176#comment121371673_68678038).